# Dont see an edit option in data tables displayed using dynamic data set

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I have created a asp.net Dynamic data linq to sql web site. After creating the project, one table is added using linq to SQL classes.

On running the project, data from the table is visible but edit button is not seen.
Edit button can be seen in the code in list.aspx but on running only table contents are seen without edit option.
In code i see all the options  mentioned in Global.asax

```
routes.Add(New DynamicDataRoute("{table}/{action}.aspx") With {
    .Constraints = New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.Action = "List|Details|Edit|Insert"}),
    .Model = DefaultModel})
```

Do you know if we have to do anything to make edit option available ?

Here is the complete file

```
<%@ Application Language="VB" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.Routing" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System.Web.DynamicData" %>

<script RunAt="server">
Private Shared s_defaultModel As New MetaModel
Public Shared ReadOnly Property DefaultModel() As MetaModel
    Get
        Return s_defaultModel
    End Get
End Property

Public Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    '                     IMPORTANT: DATA MODEL REGISTRATION 
    ' Uncomment this line to register a LINQ to SQL model for ASP.NET Dynamic Data.
    ' Set ScaffoldAllTables = true only if you are sure that you want all tables in the
    ' data model to support a scaffold (i.e. templates) view. To control scaffolding for
    ' individual tables, create a partial class for the table and apply the
    ' <ScaffoldTable(true)> attribute to the partial class.
    ' Note: Make sure that you change "YourDataContextType" to the name of the data context
    ' class in your application.
     DefaultModel.RegisterContext(GetType(aimmdsDataContext), New ContextConfiguration() With {.ScaffoldAllTables = True})

    ' The following statement supports separate-page mode, where the List, Detail, Insert, and 
    ' Update tasks are performed by using separate pages. To enable this mode, uncomment the following 
    ' route definition, and comment out the route definitions in the combined-page mode section that follows.
    routes.Add(New DynamicDataRoute("{table}/{action}.aspx") With {
        .Constraints = New RouteValueDictionary(New With {.Action = "List|Details|Edit|Insert"}),
        .Model = DefaultModel})

    ' The following statements support combined-page mode, where the List, Detail, Insert, and
    ' Update tasks are performed by using the same page. To enable this mode, uncomment the
    ' following routes and comment out the route definition in the separate-page mode section above.
    'routes.Add(New DynamicDataRoute("{table}/ListDetails.aspx") With {
    '    .Action = PageAction.List,
    '    .ViewName = "ListDetails",
    '    .Model = DefaultModel})

    'routes.Add(New DynamicDataRoute("{table}/ListDetails.aspx") With {
    '    .Action = PageAction.Details,
    '    .ViewName = "ListDetails",
    '    .Model = DefaultModel})
End Sub

Private Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes)
End Sub

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your route should contains the "Edit" value

```
 routes.Add(new DynamicDataRoute("{table}/{action}.aspx")
        {
            Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "List|Details|Edit|Insert" }),
            Model = DefaultModel
        });
```

Does your table have editing permissions ? bcz dynamic data uses all the database checks,permissions

Comment: Thanks Waqar just seen u reply while i was editing my question.. Do u see any other reason of edit option not seen ?

Comment: Thanks Waqar for looking into. I added complete file

Comment: @tectrendz Edit option is shown and it is disabled or it is completely not shown ?

Comment: @tectrendz Does your table have editing permissions  ? bcz dynamic data uses all the database checks,permissions

Comment: Thanks Waqar seems tables didnt have primary key set.. Thanks for looking into.. After adding a primary key i could get edit option

Comment: @tectrendz welcome. Keys should be present otherwise how dynamic data will know which column is related to which table.